# Compare dates in varchar with mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to compare two dates in a column called " fecha_registro " , this column is varchar (100), I'm trying to compare him with this date code:

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db   = "gimnasio";

mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);

$from = "2010-02-06";
$to = "2015-11-08";

$consulta = mysql_query("SELECT id_cliente FROM clientes WHERE fecha_registro BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'");
$cantidad = mysql_num_rows($consulta);

echo $cantidad;

?>
```

the problem is that you never find any record when multiple records that meet that pattern

The structure of the "clients" table is this :

[image]

And the records like this:

[image]

please , as I fix this ?

Comment: Convert the `varchar` to a `date` field. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html Maybe you could use this, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp and `strtotime` in PHP. I'd convert the column type though, it will save you time in the future.

Comment: i agree with chris85.

Comment: Every time you store a date in a field type other than `DATE` or `DATETIME` a DBA kills a kitten.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 SELECT id_cliente FROM clientes WHERE  
 DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(fecha_registro, '%Y-%c-%e'), '%Y-%m-%d')
 BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by this way

```
SELECT id_cliente FROM clientes WHERE  
STR_TO_DATE(fecha_registro, '%Y-%m-%d')
BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'
```